# Guardar o Date.now() no postgres

Tags: postgresql, timestamp

Olá, eu gostaria de saber qual o tipo de dado eu uso na coluna time da minha table, que vai armazenar o `Date.now()` do Javascript, ele retorna um inteiro como este 1591181717431. Eu pensei em usar o big int, alguém tem uma ideia melhor?

Comment: E se ao invés de pegar o `Date.now()` tu pegar o `new Date()` e armazenar como Timestamp no banco?

Comment: Eu vi uma galera falando que é muito bom estudar timestamp e UTC, acho que vou fazer o que voce falou Denis. Vlw. Grato.

Comment: Por acaso existe alguma particularidade em sua aplicação que torne o `Date.now()` do Javascript diferente do `now()` do PostgreSQL? Se não tiver coloque como cláusula DEFAULT no campo de sua tabela.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Esse número inteiro se trata da quantidade de milissegundos que se passaram desde a data de `01/01/1970` às `00:00:00` até o momento atual. Conhecido formalmente por [Era Unix](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Era_Unix).

O Postgres é capaz de fazer a conversão de um inteiro representando a Era Unix em segundos para o tipo `TIMESTAMP` por meio da função [`to_timestamp()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/functions-datetime.html), veja só:

```
CREATE TABLE tb_foobar
(
    id INTEGER,
    datahora TIMESTAMP
);


INSERT INTO tb_foobar (id, datahora) VALUES (1, to_timestamp(1591181717431 / 1000));
INSERT INTO tb_foobar (id, datahora) VALUES (2, to_timestamp(1591182735732 / 1000));
INSERT INTO tb_foobar (id, datahora) VALUES (3, to_timestamp(1581182718337 / 1000));
```

Consultando Tabela:

```
SELECT id, datahora FROM tb_foobar;
```

Saída:

```
| id |             datahora |
|----|----------------------|
|  1 | 2020-06-03T10:55:17Z |
|  2 | 2020-06-03T11:12:15Z |
|  3 | 2020-02-08T17:25:18Z |
```

Veja funcionando no [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/cdba1/4)

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
new Date().toLocaleString();
```

Mas eu recomendo que se vc quiser salvar a data que o registro for inserido no banco, eu faria assim:

```
alter table tabela alter column datahora set default current_date;
```

dessa forma toda vez que você inserir um registro ele vai pegar a hora e data do sistema e salvar no registro

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10211145/getting-current-date-and-time-in-javascript